# TinyMCE/FCKeditor not able to browse for files

Tags: plugins, tinymce, fckeditor, modx, modx-evolution

I changed some permissions on my server and somehow broke TinyMCE so that it can no longer browse for images and files.

I changed the permissions back to what they were but the issue still persists - when I go to browse for files I am just presented with a blank screen:

Would anyone know how to repair this?

(PS using ModX Evo CMS)

EDIT: what I see on console on the edit resource page (nothing appears when I open the console on the browsing window):

```
6
Refused to set unsafe header "Connection" index.php:1
Uncaught Error: IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1 /assets/plugins/tinymce/jscripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js:1
2
Refused to set unsafe header "Connection" index.php:1
```

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Step one: Open Firebug (or any other inspector) and see is there's any errors there. js-files missing etc. Step two: Post any relevant stuff from the error.log (both Modx and php).

Answer (score 0):

In case you do use standard installation of tinymce i suggest you reinstall tinymce over the files on the server.

Comment: Thanks, but I have tried that with several versions on Tiny MCE to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Try checking all the file names for anything that might contain special character. A em dash, n dash, possibly left quote ”, right quote etc...

I would do this via ftp to make sure you can see all the files in admin section. Rename any of the files that might have questionable characters and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks - would you know which file names in particular (what directory I should be looking at)?

Comment: Check the /assets directory. Special characters are kind of hard to spot sometimes but if anything is not the standard a-z or numbers 0-9 I would try renaming it so it is. Here is a list of a lot of them to look out for: http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/special_characters/